# How to close cd tray in Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have burned a DVD on our remote server, using external USB DVD burner (Matshita uj8e1).

After successful burn the system ejected the tray. Now I have a problem with getting the tray with the burned DVD back to the drive.

I searched Google and most of the things I found work only in Win7 or XP or even below. I have tried using tools like Wizmo, NirCMD, but without success.

Is there any way at all to remotely close a drive tray in Windows Server 2012r2?

Comment: External unit as in laptop style drive (that requires somebody to actually push the tray, which is not motorized)?

Comment: According to google that is one of those. No automatic closing. Google for "Matshita uj8e1 picture". It would also not be USB attached... this is one of these super slim getting sometimes integrated into 1RU cases.

Comment: It's this burner: http://www.amazon.com/Rosewill-Aluminum-External-Burner-ROD-EX002/dp/B003J86QYO/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top?ie=UTF8. The Matshita is inside of it. You are right with not motorized tray, thank you for the answers.

Comment: To remotely close tray of laptop-style drive, send email to coworker nearby server.

Comment: If this is going to be a recurring issue, I'd suggest using a CD/DVD burning program that gives you the choice of whether to eject the burned disc once burning is complete. CDRTFE is a portable app that has that option in its settings, the program you're using might as well.

Comment: @Twisty, this is what we did. Not noticing that this burner is not motorized was a mistake.

Comment: @DanC, thank you for the program, I will note it for the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Matshita uj8e1 is a laptop-type unit (I guess it's enclosed in some usb enclosure). Those units do not have a motorized tray, therefore they require the tray to be mechanically pushed in order to close.

Answer (score 9):

That [appears](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-8X-DVD-RW-Drive-Panasonic_764738451.html) a laptop style slimline DVD drive which is spring loaded and not motorized, so **no**. It requires manual closure.

Full sized DVD drives are motorised and often using that same eject function on a DVD drive that is already open will close it again.

The typical approach  on servers is rather than creating actual DVD's, to create DVD images,  which you then download.